# Why are labels not moving along with the image?

Tags: html, css

Why are the labels not moving along with the images (both back and front part of human anatomy) in mobile devices like Galaxy S8 and iPhones?
Here is the link to the site **https://local-physio.co.uk/.**
Please help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a question, you need to include the relevant code with it not just a link. In the future, if that link is no longer working your question becomes worthless. Please follow the [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening, simply because in the element with classes `.line .middleback` that make the line between the body and the label, the width is defined with fixed-size units (px), as those aren't flexible and won't change, even if the width or height of the screen changes. The green line will go beyond the screen width.

What you should do, is changing these elements width to a flexible viewport like **vw** or **%**.

Example with vw: `width:10vw;` is equal to 10% of with of the viewport (screen).

Example with %: `width:10%;` is equal to 10% of with of the parent element.

Comment: As you suggested, it got fixed for Galaxy and iPhone 6,7, 8 but the problem now lurks for iPad and iPhone Plus series, is there anything I missed? obrigado

Comment: You should probably use media queries, where you basicly will set different width sizes for different screen sizes.